# C# regex for assembly style hex numbers

Tags: c#, regex, assembly, numbers, hex

I'm new to regex and I want to highlight hexadecimal numbers in Assembly style. Like this:

$00
$FF
$1234
($00)
($00,x)
and even hexadecimal numbers that begin with #.

So far I wrote "$[A-Fa-f0-9]+" to see if it highlights numbers beginning with $ but it doesn't. Why? And can someone help me with what I'm doing? Thanks.

Comment: There is no getting around the fact that you need to sit down and learn regex syntax. See: [http://www.regular-expressions.info/](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a great, free tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a back slash before $ and your regex will work like so

```
\$[A-Fa-f0-9]+
```

$ is a valid regex character that matches with end of string. So if your pattern contains dollar then you need to escape it. See [regex reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for details

Comment: Just to clarify, since the OP said "new to regex," certain characters are special to the shell, and thus have to be "escaped" to indicate you want the literal "$", and not it's special meaning

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just one more question: How can I make it ignore the string if it has additional non hexadecimal characters in it? For example, I get a match if I do "$FG".

Comment: but a $ at the end and ^ at the start of your pattern which would mean the entire string has to be hex

Answer (score 1):

This should cover all those cases, including the cases in which you get a # instead of a $

```
public Regex MyRegex = new Regex(
          "^(\\()?[\\$#][0-9a-fA-F]+(,x)?(?(1)\\))[\\s]*$",
        RegexOptions.Singleline
        | RegexOptions.Compiled
        );
```

The unescaped sequence for the single line: `^(\()?[\$#][0-9a-fA-F]+(,x)?(?(1)\))[\s]*$`

That should validate on a per-line match.

By the way, I made this regex pretty quickly using [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

Comment: That isn't what expresso is telling me. I tested it on: $FF
$1234
($00)
($00,x)
#FF
#1234
(#00)
(#00,x)

Comment: Well then I honestly think .NET regex is terrible given the number of problems I have had with it in the past. :\

Comment: My experience hasn't been the best either, I've had regular expressions that parse faster in JavaScript, than in Compiled Regular Expressions in C#. I'm not sure if there are implementation subtleties that I don't know of, but that can't be good.