# RegEx for assembly number

Tags: c, regex, assembly

I'd like to convert an assembly code to C, but i have trouble changing the number formats. It's a bit similar, to this:
[C# regex for assembly style hex numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857275/c-sharp-regex-for-assembly-style-hex-numbers) but my numbers are ending with an "H" like: 00CH, FFH, etc.
The major problem is, that the imput strings are like:

- -33H
- RAM4END-AVERH-1-1
- AVERH+10H+1
- 1

I'm thinking of sg like `(?<prevStuff>)(?<hexa>)(?<nextStuff>)` format, in which case i could simply leave the prev and nextStuff and the hexa would be like: 33,[no mach],10,[no match]
I'm kind of new in here, sry for the misunds
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to do *what* with regex?  How many problems do you have?

Comment: I don't understand what language this question is about.  C#?  Or C?

Comment: I use the regex in C# the output would be C.
I want to extract the [0-9a-fA-F]H number to a variable

Comment: What has to fit in what environments?

Comment: The regex should match in code environments like above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be trying to create is a lexical analyzer or **lexer**. It takes an input string and returns tokens found from a series of rules. You can read more about lexical analysis [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

This regular expression will match the first two numbers:

```
[+-]?[0-9a-fA-F]+[H]
```

The third one is not a number but a expression. Using the following rules you can match all the tokens:

- `[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]` → `identifier`
- `[+-][0-9a-fA-F]+H` → `hexadecimal number`
- `[0-9]+` → `decimal number`

To convert the input to another language like C, you can create an [Abstract Syntax Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from the lexer output. A syntax tree represents the structure of the code as statements and expressions. Then the AST can be used to emit C code based on the statements found.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears you're looking for "items" that start with a sign (not including operational signs such as `a - b` but including those such as the second `-` in `a - -b`) or a digit and end with a `H`.

So, once you've split up your expression into components, you should just be able to detect something like:

```
[+\-0-9][0-9a-fA-F]H
```

and replace them with the equivalent C value.

For example, here's a good shell script (needs Perl for the regex stuff) to start with as it shows the possibilities:

```
#!/bin/bash
list='-14H 14H 027H 42 -17 0cH -0dH VAR1 -VAR2H'
for t1 in $list; do
    for t2 in $list; do
        expr=$t1-$t2
        xlat=$(echo $expr | perl -pne 's/\b([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]*)H\b/0x\1/g')
        echo ORIG: $expr XLAT: $xlat
    done
done
```

By using the `\b` word boundary matcher, it doesn't have to worry about the distinction between operators and signs at all.